# Vgg16 for gender detection (male,female)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, vgg-net

We have used vgg16 and freeze top layers and retrain the last 4 layers on gender dataset 12k male and 12k female. It gives very low accuracy especially for male. We are using the IMDB dataset. On female test data it gives female as output but on male it gives same output.

```
vgg_conv=VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

Freeze the layers except the last 4 layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]: 
    layer.trainable = False

Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_conv)

Add new layers
model.add(layers.Flatten()) 
model.add(layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5)) model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

nTrain=16850 nTest=6667

train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

batch_size = 12 batch_size1 = 12

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size1, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-6), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator( train_generator, steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size, epochs=3, validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=test_generator.samples/test_generator.batch_size, verbose=1)

model.save('gender.h5')
```

Testing Code:

```
model=load_model('age.h5') 
img=load_img('9358807_1980-12-28_2010.jpg', target_size=(224,224)) 
img=img_to_array(img) 
img=img.reshape((1,img.shape[0],img.shape[1],img.shape[2])) 
img=preprocess_input(img) 
yhat=model.predict(img) 
print(yhat.size) 
label=decode_predictions(yhat)

label=label[0][0]

print('%s(%.2f%%)'% (label[1],label[2]*100))
```

Comment: You should re-indent your prediction code for better readability.

Comment: Problem is that it predict female as female but male as female too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are saving the model as `gender.h5` and during testing you are loading the model `age.h5`. Probably you have added different code for the testing here.

**Coming to improving the accuracy of the program -**

1. Most importantly is that you are using `loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'`, change it to `loss = 'binary_crossentropy'` in `model.compile` as you have just 2 classes. So your 
   `model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])` will look like this.
2. Also change `class_mode='categorical'` to `class_mode='binary'` in `flow_from_directory`.
3. As `categorical_crossentropy` goes hand in hand with `softmax` activation in the last layer, and if you change the loss to `binary_crossentropy` the last activation should also be changed to `sigmoid`. So last layer should be `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`.
4. You have added 2 `Dense` layers of `4096`, this will add `4096 * 4096 = ‭16,777,216‬` weights to be learnt by the model. Reduce them may be to `1026` and `512` respectively.
5. You have added `Dropout` layer of `0.5`, that is to keep the 50% of neurons off during the epoch. That is huge number. Better is to drop off the `Dropout` layer and use to only if your model is `overfitting`.
6. Set `batch_size = 1`. As you have very less input let every epoch have same number of steps as input records.
7. Use Data Augmentation technique like `horizontal_flip`, `vertical_flip`, `shear_range`, `zoom_range` of `ImageDataGenerator` to generate the new batches of training and validation images during every `epoch`.
8. Train your model for large number of `epoch`. You are just training for `epoch=3`, that is too less for learning the weights. Train for `epoch=50` and later trim the number.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.